# How to submit responses to google-forms with python?

Tags: python, forms

I'm trying to write a Python-Script which makes it possible to submit responses in Google-Forms like this one:
https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdpiraT-JU6B5GOQ5ejCOBp7kNn0-MU4K3Vw30umxzEi7mVwg/viewform

But how do I send the POST and how can I find out, what this POST should actually contain ? How to identify the categories ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Simply send a Post to this url:

`https://docs.google.com/forms/u/0/d/e/1FAIpQLSdpiraT-JU6B5GOQ5ejCOBp7kNn0-MU4K3Vw30umxzEi7mVwg/formResponse?entry.2122680879=HP&entry.1875590270=Samsung&entry.494640498=Paolo`

Would do the trick.

You can view the sent request with Chrome inspect - network - formResponse.

Open your form URL, select the answers. Right-click any element, select inspect. Go to network tab and click submit. You will see the formResponse on the top of network activities. View the form data at the bottom.

Now go to Python and do:

```py
import requests
url = "your url"

requests.post(url)
```

Comment: How do I use options with "&"?

Comment: What does it mean to `use options with &?` To pass in any answer you just add a entry starts with &, even if the answer itself contains &